# What's special about Cobb–Douglas utility relative to the rest of the CES family?

Tags: cobb-douglas, ces-function, measuring-utility, nonexpert

My question concerns CES utility functions, which have the form
$$u(x) = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j^{\rho} \right)^{1/\rho}$$
for utility parameters $a_j$, an elasticity parameter $\rho$, and some allocation of goods given by $x$.

When $\rho=1$ we have **linear utility**,  or **perfect substitution**, with $$u(x) = a^T x$$ The level sets of $u$ are straight lines, and it is always possible to achieve the same utility by exchanging one good for another in some fixed ratio. **I can see this arising in real life:** Two bags of flour are perfectly interchangeable, and the only thing that matters to the buyer is their size and cost.

When $\rho \to -\infty$ we have **Leontief utility**, or **perfect complementarity**, with $$u(x) = \min_j a_j x_j$$ The level sets of $u$ are L-shaped, and  optimal utility is always achieved by purchasing goods in a  target ratio given by $a$. **This also makes sense:** If I am making a recipe that calls for two units of egg for every unit of sugar, having twice as much sugar makes no difference unless I also have twice as much egg.

Most situations are more complicated than this, however, and the nice thing about the CES form and its $\rho$ parameter is that it lets us capture situations that don't sit at one of these extremes. A baker can replace sugar with brown sugar, but not arbitrarily. Setting $\rho$ to some value between $1$ and $-\infty$ captures this imperfect substitutability. But the precise value of $\rho$ depends on the situation at hand: if the ingredients are pretty good substitutes, maybe $\rho = 0.8$; if they are fairly poor substitutes, maybe $\rho = -10$.

If we take the limit as $\rho \to 0$, we get a utility function that has a nice name,
the Cobb–Douglas utility function. It also has a nice form:

$$u(x) = \prod_j x_j^{a_j}$$

But is there anything that's truly *special* about this case?

From my standpoint, it looks like the Cobb–Douglas utility is just one arbitrary point along the continuum running from linear to Leontief. Perhaps it gets a name because it was discovered before the generalized CES family, but I can't see why there's anything especially meaningful about it beyond the simplicity of the form. Is this argument fair?

Is there a reason why we might assume $\rho$ is close to zero if we have ruled out the linear and Leontief cases?

Does Cobb–Douglas utility correspond to an "idealized" situation like the flour or egg/sugar examples above?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supposed to be an answer, just a comment: Cobb-Douglas function is named after the paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/1811556 (1928).

Most cases of production functions have returns to scale equal to one, which is the Cobb-Douglas form. It is not special, it is common.

CES function was generalized by Dixit and Stiglitz in the paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/1831401 (1977).